# How not to stop owl carousel on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, sliders

Currently the carousel stops when you hover it, I've added `autoplayHoverPause:false` but it doesn't seem to change anything.
Is there another option that I could use to stop it from stopping when it's hovered?

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplayHoverPause:false,
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `autoplayHoverPause` is correct property. Moreover, `false` is a default value for `autoplayHoverPause`, so it shouldn't pause carousel on hover even if you don't set this property.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at JSFiddle?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, sorry, but I can`t do it.

Comment: Try  stopOnHover : false,

Comment: @j.rey, nothing has changed...

Comment: just remove "autoplayHoverPause: false" line and it will not stop, it will loop forever

Answer (score 9):

To stop the slide on hover just add the following to your script:

```
autoplayHoverPause:true
```

Answer (score 3):

As j.rey noted, it seems `stopOnHover` is the correct way to start/stop autoplay on hover per the specs on this page:

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing

I don't see any reference to `autoplayHoverPause` in the docs. Maybe that was an older version?

Comment: `autoplayHoverPause` is in [docs here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#autoplayhoverpause) but `stopOnHover` is not!

Answer (score 1):

Just add **stopOnHover:true** in your script.

Comment: Wouldn't that actually have the opposite effect?  They want it to continue when hovering, and setting this parameter seems like it would cause it to stop when you hover...

Answer (score 0):

set `autoplayHoverPause:false`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLo1vkeg/)

Answer (score 0):

stopOnHover:true
https npmjs.com package react-owl-carousel

Answer (score 0):

`stopOnHover:true` https npmjs.com package react-owl-carousel

Use `mouseDrag : false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify hover `css` which is created through `owl.carousle.js`

```
<script>
$(".owl-wrapper-outer").mouseover(function(){
                $('.owl-wrapper').css({
                "-webkit-transition": "",
                "-moz-transition": "",
                "-o-transition": "",
                "transition": "",  
                    });

                });
</script>
```